# Distributing Licensed Metro XAML Control Suites via NuGet

Tags: tfs, custom-controls, microsoft-metro, nuget

I am currently involved in building an extensive custom control suite in XAML/C++ which which will be a 'paid-for' package, which will be available to Metro XAML developers for a licence fee.

I want to allow customers to purchase a licence via our company website, then access their purchase via Nuget within Visual Studio.

My questions are:

1) Can I utilise the NuGet packaging technology for 'paid' components (users will need to enter credentials or licence key to get them from our private Nuget repository - or something similar)

2) We would want to host our own Nuget repository to control access, and hope to hook into our TFS system - does anyone know if this is possible ?

The scenario we are trying to create is where a potential customer comes to our website, buys our control suite, downloads our controls (securely) in Visual Studio via Nuget and gets automatic updates. On the flip side, we do all of our development to TFS, press a 'deploy' button and the update gets automatically published to our TFS-based Nuget repository.

I know this is a complex multi-faceted question, but any suggestions would be welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, NuGet is not supposed to contain any built-in security mechanisms - it is simple zip archive in [OPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) format. Once your client took a package he can send it to anyone. You can sell a service - freshest releases, bug-fix support and so on.

What about practice. You can implement NuGet API And Share to your customers only feed.

- Do Any authentication you want.
- Create as much feeds as you need (according to your licensing policy).
- Every feed will contain only subset of your packages
- Create a package on-the-fly with built-in customer key (it goes against moral rules of the project) - cause package doesn't have a signature.

But this gives you ability to enable to customer to use NuGet as a platform to update your packages along with any shared packages.

AFAIK, there is no public gallery for NuGet (Nuget Gallery, Nuget.Server, and so on) wich will restrict access to the packages.